# How to use aws Lightsail for my react build

Tags: reactjs, port, web-hosting, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to use lightsail to host a website. 
It almost works fine but I have to write example.com:5000 but I don't know what to do to remove this :5000.
I used npm run build to create a file and I use pm2 to serve it automatically on this port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using PM2 to serve the react application, you can serve it directly in port 80 by doing the following:

1. Connect to your server (Note: Only root can bind ports which are less than 1024 so that's why we're going to use authbind which allow this port binding for non-root users)
2. Bind the 80 port using `authbind` by executing the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install authbind` Install the authbind package

`sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80` Create a "binding file" to bind port 80

`sudo chown YOUR-USER /etc/authbind/byport/80` Make your user the owner of this file (make sure to replace YOUR-USER with your username)

`chmod 755 /etc/authbind/byport/80` Set the access right for this file

3. Start the app by using `authbind --deep pm2`

You can view more information about these steps via the official PM2 documentation: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/specifics/

Also, if you're just serving a React application, you can use S3 to host it since it's pretty cheap and you gives you advantages such as CDN and other features. If you're doing that just make sure to enable CORS in your S3 bucket.